# AngularJS - inject string from model to HTML's tag name

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

is it possible to inject string into html's tag name with angular?

Something like this:

```
    <div ng-repeat="type in types">
        <bettype-{{type.id}}></bettype-{{type.id}}>
    </div>
```

The output I need is:

```
<bettype-1></bettype-1>
<bettype-2></bettype-2>
```

I am also using polymer (this way I am creating the custom html tags).

Comment: Do you want that tag to function as an Angular directive, or is this just to be rendered and interpreted by some other engine?   If the former, you'll need to call $compile on the content first, will look for a snippet to borrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to create a directive which creates custom elements, something like:

```
.directive('bettype', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function($element, $attr) {
            return function($scope, $element, $attr) {
                // Create new element here with $attr.number
                var number = $attr.number,
                    element = angular.element('<bettype-'+number+'></bettype-'+number+'>');
                // Replace newly created element
                $element.replaceWith(element);
                $compile($element)($scope);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Not sure if that will work, but probably that's the way to go...

Note: I don't think it\s a good idea to have dashed separated elements like `bettype-1`..